# Is there anyway of fixing unresolved reference: until in android studio

Tags: kotlin

Whenever I run this code I keep getting errors that say `unresolved reference: until.` Please can anyone help me out with this?

```
for (row in 0 until nSquares) {
    counter = if (row and 1 == 0) {
        paint!!.setARGB(
                   200 ,
                   SquareOne[0],
                   SquareOne[1],
                   SquareOne[2])
    }
    ...
```

Comment: What is the type of `nSquares`? Is Kotlin enabled in the project?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your gradle app level on top inside plugin

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Or in new version

```
id:'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Or you can also use it for like this

```
for (row in 0..nSquare){
}
```